# JSoup randomly throws java.io.IOException: stream is closed when running from browser

Tags: javafx, jsoup

I'm having some weird JSoup problem when running my JavaFX application from the browser (or as web-start).

When I run from inside the IDE (Eclipse or Netbeans) or as a standalone app, it runs normally. When I try to run as a web-start or from the browser (Chrome), JSoup randomly throws a "java.io.IOException: stream is closed".

The site I'm trying to parse is thepiratebay.sx. When I first run the application (from browser), I get this error. With the application running, if I try to parse again, than it works... sometimes.

The JSoup code:

```
try {
    //TODO: Change to HttpFetcher. This method is reporting "stream is closed" when running on browser
    Connection con = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .timeout(HTTP_TIMEOUT)
            .userAgent(UserAgentGenerator.getUserAgent())
            .followRedirects(false);
    doc = con.get();
    System.out.println("Fetching... " + url);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Parser connect must have timed out, no results. " + url);
    fetchFailed[i] = true;
    continue;
}       
finally {
    i++;
    if (CommonTFUtils.isAllTrue(fetchFailed)) {
        throw new HttpException("Fetcher failed on every URL of " + response.getSite_name());
    }
}
```

And the exception thrown:

```
CacheEntry[http://thepiratebay.sx/browse/207/0/7]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Tue May 14 14:28:16 BRT 2013,length=-1
java.io.IOException: stream is closed
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:468)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
    at com.package.torrent.parser.GenericParser.search(GenericParser.java:147)
    at com.package.torrent.parser.GenericParser.browse(GenericParser.java:82)
    at com.package.search.TrackerSearch.searchTracker(TrackerSearch.java:69)
    at com.package.search.TrackerSearch.searchAllTrackers(TrackerSearch.java:40)
    at com.package.search.TrackerSearch.searchAllTrackers(TrackerSearch.java:23)
    at com.package.search.MovieBrowser.browseTrackers(MovieBrowser.java:49)
    at com.package.ui.browse.BrowseController$MovieBrowserTask.call(BrowseController.java:237)
    at com.package.ui.browse.BrowseController$MovieBrowserTask.call(BrowseController.java:213)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1259)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a known issue with JSoup. https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/336

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution. Place this code before you ever call JSoup. Apparently, applets and web start set this value to true. Now, I wonder why Sun forces you to access a static variable non-statically.

```
new URL("jar:file://dummy.jar!/").openConnection().setDefaultUseCaches(false);
```

JSoup doesn't handle well when the URL is cached and treats it as an exception.